# Using Matlab SVM model in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, libsvm

I have used libsvm in Matlab to create an SVM model. I can't create the model in the code where I do the prediction so I need to save the model and use it later. I want to use that model in my C++ code to make predictions. I know how to predict in matlab itself using `svmpredict`, but I want to save the model created in matlab and use it in C++ for predictions. Fist of all, is it possible? If so how do I save the model in matlab and call it back in C++?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to save the parameters learned by the model in a csv file. The returned model from svmtrain is a struct. One of the elements of this struct are the model parameters. You could then read this into your C++ file.

However, this seems redundant because libSVM is already written in C. Hence, the predict function being called is being called in C.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it is not clear to me. How do I use the model parameters saved in CSV file in C++? If I want to make a prediction in C++ with these parameters, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is being able to predict values in your C++ code, one thing you can do is extracting the model parameters in matlab and use it in predictions in your C++ code.

You may already know that you can manually do the predictions by substituting the required values and predicting based on the sign.

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/126410) has information about what parameters to extract in the case of  RBF kernel and how you can make predictions.